# DataTable iteration gives unwanted data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections, datatable, ienumerable

I am iterating through a DataTable using SqlDataAdapter and storing it in a list. 
Here is my code.

```
public IEnumerable<DataRow> GetRecord()
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM mv_tbl", "ConnectionString"))
    {
        da.Fill(table);
        List<DataRow> list = new List<DataRow>();
        foreach (DataRow r in table.Rows)
        {
            list.Add(r);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

This gives me a result which has unnecessary data also. Here is the result.

```
[{"RowError":"",
"RowState":2,
"Table":[{"mv_id":2,
"mv_name":"Up",
"mv_link":"link",
"user":"admin@gmail.com",
"db_tstamp":"2020-01-01T01:50:00"},
{"mv_id":3,
"mv_name":"8 Below",
"mv_link":"link",
"user":"admin@gmail.com",
"db_tstamp":"2020-01-01T02:49:00"}],
"ItemArray":[2,"Up","link","admin@gmail.com","2020-01-01T01:50:00"],
"HasErrors":false},
{"RowError":"",
"RowState":2,
"Table":[{"mv_id":2,
"mv_name":"Up",
"mv_link":"link",
"user":"admin@gmail.com",
"db_tstamp":"2020-01-01T01:50:00"},
{"mv_id":3,
"mv_name":"8 Below",
"mv_link":"link",
"user":"admin@gmail.com",
"db_tstamp":"2020-01-01T02:49:00"}],
"ItemArray":[3,"8 Below","link","admin@gmail.com","2020-01-01T02:49:00"],
"HasErrors":false}]
```

My expected result is.

```
[{"mv_id":2,
    "mv_name":"Up",
    "mv_link":"link",
    "user":"admin@gmail.com",
    "db_tstamp":"2020-01-01T01:50:00"},
    {"mv_id":3,
    "mv_name":"8 Below",
    "mv_link":"link",
    "user":"admin@gmail.com",
    "db_tstamp":"2020-01-01T02:49:00"}]
```

Here is a screenshot from the database.

[image: Table Records screenshot]

My original question is here.

[How can I return a list of rows of dynamic table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59549332/how-can-i-return-a-list-of-rows-of-dynamic-table)

Where am I making a mistake.?

Comment: "gives me a result " - Where exactly are you receiving these results. Is this a web application/api ?

Comment: @AnuViswan yes its an webapi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the `DataTable` to a collection of `Dictionary<string,object>`  (`EnumerableRowCollection<Dictionary<string,object>`)

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(row => dt.Columns
                                     .Cast<DataColumn>()
                                     .ToDictionary(column => column.ColumnName,column => row[column]));
return result;
```

This would also produce the desired Json return from Web API.

Alternatively, you could return the `DataTable` itself or make use of collection of anonymous types or user defined class.

Comment: voila..I've been banging my head for 2 days/nights...all I just needed to do was return the table. That's it... Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to serialize your list (`GetRecord` return result).

But before serialize you need to pass datatable to below function (in your case you are returning `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, try passing datatable) and convert it into List. Now try serializing this `List<dynamic>`.

```
public  List<dynamic> ConvertToDynamic(DataTable dt)
{
        var lstOfDynamic = new List<dynamic>();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            dynamic dyn = new  System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();

            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                var dic = (IDictionary<string, object>)dyn;
                dic[col.ColumnName] = row[col];
            }

            lstOfDynamic.Add(dyn);
        }

        return lstOfDynamic;
    }
```

Hope this will help you.